# Is Rudin correct here? Fubini's theorem and product measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, harmonic-analysis

Let $X, Y$ be locally compact Hausdorff spaces with nonnegative regular measures $\mu, \lambda$.  By definition (in the book I'm reading) a regular measure is a Borel measure for which every Borel set can be approximated from below by compact sets, or from above by open sets.  In the appendix in Rudin's book *Fourier Analysis on Groups*, he makes a couple of statements which I have not found anywhere else.  I just wanted to confirm that they are correct.  First there is:

> There is a unique regular measure $\mu \times \lambda$ on $X \times Y$ for which $\mu \times \lambda(A \times B) = \mu(A) \lambda(B)$ for $A \subseteq X, B \subseteq Y$ Borel.

This statement seems fishy to me, because I know product measures are in general not uniquely determined by their values on products of Borel sets.  Some things can happen when $X$ or $Y$ is not $\sigma$-finite.  Next there is:

> ("Fubini's theorem") If $f \geq 0$ is a Borel function on $X \times Y$, then $$ \int\limits f d(\mu \times \lambda) = \int\limits_X \int\limits_Y f(x,y)d\lambda(y) d\mu(x) = \int\limits_Y \int\limits_X f(x,y)d \mu(x) d \lambda(y) $$

The reason I am concerned with this is that there is a **very** similar result stated in Hewitt and Ross, *Abstract Harmonic Analysis*, Theorem 13.9, which makes the same claim for $f \geq 0$ Borel (although they allow $f$ to take on the value infinity, Rudin clearly does not).  This theorem gives the same result, but requires the addition hypothesis that *$f$ vanishes off of a countable union of $(\mu \times \lambda)$-measurable sets which each have finite measure.*

Would any experts on the subtleties of regular measures be willing to explain why or confirm that Rudin's statements are correct?  One thing I am wondering is whether Rudin is tacitly assuming $X,Y$ and $X \times Y$ have an additional property (which is true of locally compact Hausdorff abelian groups, which is what his book is mainly concerned with), namely that each space is a disjoint union of $\sigma$-compact subspaces $X_{\alpha}$, such that every $\sigma$-compact subset of $X$ is contained in a countable union of the $X_{\alpha}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One question is what you mean by "every Borel set can be approximated by compact sets from inside and by open sets from outside". The usual definition I take (adopted by Folland, who also provides essentially the example mentions below) is that $\mu(M) = \inf_{U \subset M}\mu(U)$ (with $U$ open) should hold for all Borel sets $M$, whereas $\mu(M)=\sup{K \subset M}\mu(K)$ is only required for **open** $M$.

The standard counterexample to things like this is the following: Let $X = \Bbb{R}_d$ be the group of reals (with the usual addition), but with the discrete topology and let $Y=\Bbb{R}$.

Now, take $A\times B=\Bbb{R}_d \times \{0\}$. Note that the relevant sets are closed, hence Borel. By your requirement, $\mu\times\lambda (A \times B)= \mu(A)\lambda(B) =\infty \cdot 0=0$, where $\mu,\lambda$ are the Haar measures. Note that $\infty \cdot 0=0$ is the only sensible choice for produce measures (consider $A\times \emptyset$).

But for any open set $U \supset A \times B$, we have $U \supset \{x\}\times (0,\epsilon_x)$ for some $\epsilon_x >0$. Since $\Bbb{R}$ is uncountable, there is some $n$ and infinitely many $x_1, x_2, \dots$ with $\epsilon_{x_\ell} \geq 1/n$ for all $\ell$. Together with your assumptions on the product measure, this easily yields $\mu \times \lambda (U) = \infty$. Thus, the product is not outer regular.

Since a product measure as described by Rudin does not exist in general, talking about the Fubini problem is of little use. Anyway, the above discussion shows that a regular version of the product measure would yield $\mu\times\lambda (A\times B)=\infty$, so that your Fubuni formula fails when applied to the indicator of this set.

Finally, a very nice discussion of these topics can be found in Folland's books "Real Analysis" and "Abstract Harmonic Analysis". There he constructs a **Radon product** of two Radon measures and explains the difference to the usual product measure.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  Does this mean that (1) Rudin is not using the correct definition of "regular" here and (2) both results I mentioned are false?

Comment: @D_S: I don't have the book at hand, so I don't know the exact definition that Rudin is using. Alao, its hard to say that a definition is "incorrect". "Unusual" would be more to the point. But I think that with Rudin's definition, the Riesz representation theorem is probably false in general for non-sigma-compact spaces. For $\sigma $-finite measures (and thus for sigma compact spaces), both definitions  are equivalent IIRC.

Comment: @D_S: And yes, as stated, both results are false. But with slight modifications,  they become true. I could elaborate on that, but since the details are a bit longer, it is probably better if you could get your hands on the books by Folland.

Comment: Do you mean "A Guide to Advanced Real Analysis" or "Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and their applications?"

Comment: @D_S: The second one and also "A course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis".