# Convolution square of the Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, cantor-set, hausdorff-measure

For $0\leq d\leq 1$, let $\eta_d$ be the $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $\mathbb{R}$ (for some normalization); recall that it is translation-invariant.

**Motivation** for what follows: Up to recently, I was convinced that if $f$ and $g$ are in $L^1(\mathbb{R},\eta_d)$ (that is, Borel functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, integrable w.r.t. $\eta_d$, modulo equality $\eta_d$-a.e) one could define their convolution as usual by $(f*g)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y)\, g(x-y)\, \mathrm{d}\eta_d(x)$ and that this would satisfy $\|f*g\|_1 \leq \|f\|_1\,\|g\|_1$ as expected (where $\|f\|_1 := \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t)\, \mathrm{d}\eta_d(t)$).  Upon thinking about [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323312/are-hausdorff-measures-on-the-real-line-haar-measures-for-some-locally-compact-t/), I realized that this is not the case: the usual proof relies on translation-invariance and Fubini, but Fubini itself relies on $\sigma$-finiteness which is not true of $\eta_d$; for the Haar measure on a locally compact abelian group, which is not necessarily $\sigma$-finite, one can get away with "regularity" instead (even though [things appear to be confused](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540612/is-rudin-correct-here-fubinis-theorem-and-product-measures)), but now I'm struggling to understand what works or does not work for Hausdorff measures.  So let me ask about a concrete case:

> Let $d = \log 2/\log 3$ and let $\eta = \eta_d$ be the $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $\mathbb{R}$, normalized so that the usual Cantor middle-third set $C$ has $\eta(C)=1$.  Let $f = \mathbf{1}_C$ be the indicator function of $C$ and $\nu = f \eta$ (that is, $E \mapsto \int_E f\, \mathrm{d}\eta$) be the "uniform" probability measure on $C$.  We define the convoluted function $g := f\mathbin{*_\eta}f = f*\nu$ as
> $$x \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y)\, f(x-y)\, \mathrm{d}\eta(y) = \int_{C} f(x-y)\,\mathrm{d}\nu(y)$$
> and we define the convoluted measure $\xi := \nu*\nu$ as
> $$E \mapsto (\nu\times\nu)(\{(y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : y+z\in E\})$$

To put it more simply, $g(x)$ is the probability that, if $y$ is chosen uniformly in the Cantor set, $x-y$ also falls in the Cantor set; whereas $\xi(E)$ is the probability that two given reals $y,z$ both chosen uniformly and independently in the Cantor set have a sum in $E$.

Naïvely one would like to think that $\int_E g\, \mathrm{d}\eta = \xi(E)$ (for $E$ a Borel set) with the following "proof":
$$\begin{aligned}\int_E g\, \mathrm{d}\eta
&= \int_E\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-y)\, \mathrm{d}\nu(y)\right) \mathrm{d}\eta(x)\\
&= \int_{E\times\mathbb{R}} f(x-y)\, \mathrm{d}\nu(y)\, \mathrm{d}\eta(x)\\
&= \int_{\{(y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : y+z\in E\}} f(z)\, \mathrm{d}\nu(y)\, \mathrm{d}\eta(z)\\
&= \int_{\{(y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : y+z\in E\}} \mathrm{d}\nu(y)\, \mathrm{d}\nu(z)\\
&= \xi(E)\end{aligned}$$
but as explained above, this proof does not work.  However, both $g$ and $\xi$ are still well-defined objects.

> **Questions:**
>
> - How can we describe $g = f\mathbin{*_\eta}f$ and $\xi = \nu * \nu$ more concretely?
> - Specifically, what is the support of $g$?
> - What is the exact relation between $g$ and $\xi$?
> - Specifically, is $\xi$ absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\eta$?  (I believe it isn't.)

**Bonus question:** I am aware that the Fourier-Stieltjes transform $\hat\xi$ of $\xi$ is $u\mapsto e^{-2i\pi u} \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \cos^2(2\pi u/3^j)$ (the square of that of $\nu$).  But what is the Fourier transform of $g$?